# How to insert a module in qemu where module is in guest system?

Tags: kernel-modules, qemu

I am running qemu first time so I don't have much knowledge of it.

I am having a kernel module `hello.ko` and I want to insert it in kernel using `insmod` in an OS running in `qemu` and this module is stored in a folder which is on host system. So is there a way to run this module on guest system or I need to share it with guest system and then test it?

I searched on google there was [a solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207012/255251) which first creates isoimage and then create virtual machine:

```
genisoimage -o image.iso -r /path/to/dir
virsh attach-disk guest image.iso hdc --driver file --type cdrom --mode 
readonly
```

where guest is virtual ID of virtual machine.

But in my case `virsh list --all` gives empty output so I think there is no virtual machine.
I run qemu using

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -hda qemu-image.img -initrd initrd.img- 
4.9.1 -append "root=/dev/sda single" -m 2GB
```

where `qemu-image.img` is created using `sudo debootstrap --arch amd64 stretch $DIR` where is $DIR is a folder.